# Postman not shows my exception for non existing parameter in GET method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, docker-compose, postman

I used SpringBoot REST api with MongDB.
And I use docker compose.
In the part of Docker all are fine but in the Postman when I have GET method, if there is not exist the parameter, it is not show me the error.why?
For example:
In GET method, if the score is not exist the method should throw my exception. But it doese not work.

The GET method:

```
@GetMapping("/{score}")
        public ResponseEntity<?>  getScore(@PathParam("score") Long score){
            //Query query = new Query();
            //new Criteria();
            //query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("score").is(score));



            try {

                List<Score> sc = srepo.findByScoresc(score); 
                        //mongoTemplate.find(query, Score.class);
                return ResponseEntity.ok(sc);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(404).body("Not found!");
            }

        }
```

this is Postman:
[image: instead of showing Error 404, Not Found!, it is show Ok and empty json]

Comment: No data doesn't mean exception. The `sc` variable will have `0` size. so you get a blank array in return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No data doesn't mean exception. The `sc` variable will have `0` size. so you get a blank array in return